# what is the exact purpose of the cross compile option "--prefix"

Tags: makefile, arm, cross-compiling, prefix

It might sound like a *google first* or *consult --help* kinda question, but I did both and still dint really get a satisfing answer.

Imagine the following scenario: I have a cross-compiled RootFileSystem on my `i686` harddrive under `/tftpboot/rfs`. I am booting this `RFS` over `NFS` with my ARM-Platform. I would now like to compile `libxml`, `sqlite` and `php` to the `ARM-RFS` to extend the already installed `thttpd` server. In my understanding, `--prefix` defines a different place for `/`, so in my case my configs should be as below:

```
//libxml

./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/tftpboot/rfs
make
make install


//sqlite
./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/tftpboot/rfs   CFLAGS="-lpthread -lrt -Os -ldl" CPPFLAGS="-DSQLITe_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORAGE=3"
make
make install

//php
./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/tftpboot/rfs
    --with-thttpd=/usr/local/sbin --without-pear --with-pdo-sqlite=/usr/local --disable-all --enable-pdo 
    --with-sqlite3=/usr/local --with-config-file-path=/data --enable-libxml --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local
make
make install
```

because:

- I want to install in the normal `rootfs` hierarchy but at a rootpoint in `/tftpboot/rfs`.
- `thttpd` is already installed in `/tftpboot/rfs`. so I want to link it there
- ???

so I have to admit that I have absolutely no idea where I have to take absolute and where I have to work with relative paths. Or am I getting this all completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--prefix` tells configure where to install the programs, and where the installed program should look for its files when you run it.

If a specific project/program does not use the prefix at run-time (many don't) then it is simply the install location, and you can ignore the following. You can *usually* tell if the prefix is used by the compiled program by greping the installed binaries for the directory name (try doing an experimental install in a distinctive prefix), but that may not work if the files have debug info.

Otherwise, if you want to run it from a different location that you compiled it then here's the trick:

Assumptions:

- You want to run it from `/usr/bin` in the target system's view.
- You want to install it under `/tftpboot/rfs/usr/bin` in the build system's view.

Steps:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --build=i686-linux --host=arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi
make
make DESTDIR=/tftpboot/rfs install
```

**Warning**: `DESTDIR` is a conventional name, but some projects may choose something else (or nothing at all, in which case happy makefile hacking).